# How to add a website URL with space (%20) in a LinkedIn profile page under websites?

Tags: linkedin, url

I am trying to add my weblink which has a white space, that is, `%20` in it. When I add a website URL in a LinkedIn profile using the edit option, it shows no error. But when I click the link in my profile, it shows "Link Error".

I noticed the "%20" in the URL is replaced by "+".

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to encode the encoded space - effectively, it looks like the LinkedIn.com website is unencoding the %20 to an actual space, which it then runs through a verification check which fails, as spaces in URLs are not supported.

So if you want to have a site with a URL like:

`http://www.example.com/?id=this%20rocks`

You'd need to enter:

`http://www.example.com/?id=this%2520rocks`

Where you have encoded the ampersand of `%20` into the encoding for ampersand, which is `%25`. Essentially you are double-encoding the URL.

Comment: +1 for finding the root cause and a workaround to fix the problem, but this is probably better fixed by contacting LinkedIn and having them fix their site...

Comment: Even better would be to have a URL without spaces. Valid or no, some web servers and web browsers don't play nice with them.